# Is the squared euclidean norm a measure for the distance of two points?

Tags: normed-spaces, quadratic-forms

I like to prove that a measure for the distance $d$ of two points $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ in $R^N$ is given by the squared euclidean norm

$$d^2= \sum^N_j (a_j - b_j)^2 $$

So far I was able to show that the squared euclidean norm is no norm itself (triangular inequality not fulfilled, e.g. for $N=3$ and $\vec a =(4,4,4)$, $\vec b =(2,2,2)$, $\vec c =(0,0,0)$).

There should be a way to show this by using the minimization of a quadratic form but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

[Quadratic form as generalized distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371756/quadratic-form-as-generalized-distance) covers the same topic...

Comment: What means "measure for the distance"? *Another* distance?

Comment: Please define "measure for the distance".

Comment: "There should be a way to show this": what is *this* ?

Comment: I think they want to prove that this is a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition) over $\Bbb{R}^N$.

Comment: @Martin-Blas: Yes, _some_ Distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance).

Comment: @Did, Yves Daoust: this = the prove that the squared euclidean norm can be used as a distance-measure

Comment: @Noble Mushtak: No full metric required

Comment: So far I have no idea what your question could be.

Comment: @Benvorth the provided link doesn't seem to give a definition. Can you provide a definition for this generalized distance in the OP?

Answer (score 1):

No. Don't satisfies Triangle inequality.

For example

d([0 0 0],[2 2 2])=12 > d([0 0 0], [1 1 1]) + d( [1 1 1], [2 2 2])=6.

Comment: Thanks for your Input, I know that. I am looking for a more generalized distance defined by a quadratic form (see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371756/quadratic-form-as-generalized-distance/1371764#1371764)